# I'm trying to do an equation in C++ but it keeps outputting 1

Tags: c++

As the title says, this code is meant to calculate the probability of 2 people having the same birthday in a group of 5 but it just outputs 1, I'm fairly new to C++ so any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
float p;

p=1-(364/365)*(363/365)*(362/365)*(361/365);
cout<<p;
}
```

Comment: Your numerator and denominator are of type  integer due to which your result is also a Integer value.

Comment: *I'm fairly new to C++* -- Dividing an `int` by an `int` yielding an `int` should have been covered very early, if not right away, in the C++ book or material you're using.

Comment: @Lalitkumar Don't put answers in the comments section

Answer (score 2):

Put a .0 on each number, that way is treated as a double instead of an integer.  Integer division (364/365) equals 0

```
p=1.0-(364.0/365.0)*(363.0/365.0)*(362.0/365.0)*(361.0/365.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because after calculation `364/365` the calculates answer is an integer which is `0`.

To make it work change it like this.

```
p=1-(364/365.0)*(363/365.0)*(362/365.0)*(361/365.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the integers to floats as `/` rounds to the largest integer below the result when both types are `int`:

```
p=1-(float(364)/float(365))*(float(363)/float(365))*(float(362)/float(365))*(float(361)/float(365));
```